# In a trivially copyable struct shall the move semantics be implemented?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, move-semantics

I have such a struct:

```
template <class T> struct Dimensions
{
    T horizontal{}, vertical{};

    Dimensions() = default;
    Dimensions(const T& horizontal, const T& vertical)
        : horizontal(horizontal), vertical(vertical) {}
    Dimensions(const Dimensions& other) = default;
    Dimensions& operator=(const Dimensions& other) = default;
    Dimensions(Dimensions&& other) = default; // ?
    Dimensions& operator=(Dimensions&& other) = default; // ?
    ~Dimensions() = default;

    // ... + - * / += -= *= areNull() ...

}
```

which I instantiate like `Dimensions<int>` or `Dimensions<double>`. Since it is [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable), what would be the best policy here, generate the move constructor and move assignment operators as `= default` or avoid the implicit ones by `= delete`?

Comment: For `int` and `double` a move is the same as a copy, so move assignment and copy assignment will likely be identical. Moving is for when you can see a way to avoid copying by doing something different (or when copying is disabled, like for `unique_ptr`).

Comment: In a trivially copyable type, don't declare any copy-/move- ctor/assignment or dtor at all. Let the compiler do it for you and avoid the useless clutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> generate the move constructor and move assignment operators as `= default` or avoid the implicit ones by `= delete`?

The former, unless you want any code that attempts to `std::move` your type to fail compilation. E.g.

```
template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    T a;
    T b = std::move(a);
}

struct X
{
    X() = default;
    X(X&&) = delete;
};

int main() { foo<X>(); }
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NemLVdOBQVihcrkd)